# Extracting lists from the lists of lists and assigning them into columns in python

Tags: python-3.x, list, iteration

I have a dataset(df_norm) with a column 'geometry.coordinates' that has a list of lists(l1) as it's value:

```
    geometry.coordinates        
0   [[[23.514690935490876, 53.946715071429367], [2...
1   [[[23.549827385369554, 53.942282407709513], [2...
2   [[[23.574999999999307, 53.941666666666151], [2...
```

I need to extract the individual coordinates from each list and assign each coordinate into a separate column, to get the output similar to this:

```
    longitude1              latitude1       longitude2             latitude2            ...
    23.514690935490876  53.946715071429367   23.5127605166679412   53.961345695020002
    23.549827385369554  53.942282407709513   23.6123409888603434   53.941666666666151
    ....
```

The code I have is:

```
    def flatten_list(l1):
        flat_list = []
        for sublist in df_norm['geometry.coordinates'][0]:
            for item in sublist:
                flat_list.append(item)
        return flat_list

     for i in range(len(df_norm['geometry.coordinates'])):
         for j in df_norm['geometry.coordinates']:
             flatten_list(df_norm['geometry.coordinates'])
             var1 = flat_list[i][0]
             var2 = flat_list[i][1]
             var3 = flat_list[i][2]
             var4 = flat_list[i][3]
             var5 = flat_list[i][4]
```

I get an error:

```
  IndexError: list index out of range
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It seems your `flatten_list()` function produces a single un-nested list of all your values. However, when you index the list to assign the variables, you are using a nested notation `flat_list[i][0]`.
In order to distribute the values from your new list produced by `flatten_list()` to the corresponding variables, try changing the indices as such:

```
for i in range(len(df_norm['geometry.coordinates'])):
         for j in df_norm['geometry.coordinates']:
             flatten_list(df_norm['geometry.coordinates'])
             var1 = flat_list[i]
             var2 = flat_list[i+1]
             var3 = flat_list[i+2]
             var4 = flat_list[i+3]
             var5 = flat_list[i+4]
```

Further, if I understand your goal correctly, you want to produce lists under each of these variable names. As is, the loop will replace the values and only leave the final 5 values saved (one as each of the variables). Perhaps producing lists for each variable outside the loop and appending the values would be a better approach? Finally - a change to your `range()` parameters might be needed. Otherwise, duplicate values corresponding to one variable will be placed in the wrong variable as the temporary `i` variable progresses.

```
var1 = []
var2 = []
var3 = []
var4 = []
var5 = []
for i in range(0,len(df_norm['geometry.coordinates'],5)):
         for j in df_norm['geometry.coordinates']:
             flatten_list(df_norm['geometry.coordinates'])
             var1.append(flat_list[i])
             var2.append(flat_list[i+1])
             var3.append(flat_list[i+2])
             var4.append(flat_list[i+3])
             var5.append(flat_list[i+4])
```

Comment: I get the "IndexError: list index out of range", pointing to the last line: var5.append(flat_list[i+4])

Comment: Hmmm, might be because your list does not evenly distribute among the five variables? Is one of the columns expected to be shorter by a single value?

Answer (score 0):

You got the error could be probably because you don't assign the value returned by the function.